# Outlook 2010 Form Designer component

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, forms

Which MS Office component is required to design custom forms in Outlook? I unchecked many components during Office installation and now my Outlook lets me only to open a custom form, not create one. From the installer descriptions I cannot locate the desired one and I don't want to install all that crap.

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove features for your Office 2010 Suite, this should help you out. Here's a site that can show  you easily how to do it.

Select the whole Microsoft Office 2010 Suite and click on RUN ALL FROM MY COMPUTER. This, will install everything required for a smooth Office 2010 usage.

[Add or Remove Apps from the Microsoft Office 2007 or 2010 Suite](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9397/add-or-remove-apps-from-the-microsoft-office-2007-or-2010-suite/)